# Strange Firefox refresh bar

Tags: firefox, extension, refresh

Recently, I've been seeing Firefox present me a bar asking "Refresh the page for the changes to take effect", and giving me the option to refresh now or later, and no close icons. Like this:

[image: Firefox refresh bar]

It basically appears at a yet unknown interval, and I still haven't found if it comes from Firefox itself, or from some extension. I've checked all my active extensions' options and none of them seem to be related to this behaviour.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Is this happening on multiple websites? This looks like it's part of the site. It's part of the website's scroll area, which generally isn't the case with messages that are part of the browser.

Comment: It's happening on all websites, and frequently. It does not happen in other browsers, just Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

This might be caused by an add-on that enables and disables JavaScript, popups, etc., when changing options. Restart Firefox in [Safe mode](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-firefox-issues-using-safe-mode), which disables **all** add-ons, and see if the popup recurs.

[image: Firefox Safe Mode]

If that resolves the issue, restart in normal mode and disable *half* the add-ons. Now you know which *half* of the add-ons are problematic. Then disable half of the list that caused the issue, i.e. narrowed down to a quarter of all add-ons. Continue the binary search until you identify the cause, and remove that add-on.

Answer (score 0):

I got exactly the same behavior (same annoying light yellow bar, same buttons) at the top of most pages while using Firefox. The only changes I did before seeing that bar was installing Malwarebytes tools (MBAM) and Dr.Web Link Checker.
I tried first to disable "Link Checker" add-on and it seems to work!
I checked for any related topic on Dr.Web web site, but I found nothing relevant.
I will consolidate that solution during the following days...